# Does on after save work with the API call?

Tags: plugin, plugin-events, system-plugin, restful-api, webhooks

I want to listen to when an article has been changed and then send a request to a webhook.

If it was manually being entered then I could do an `onAfterSave` plugin.

Will this work with an API call?  Would a workflow or something work for that?

Comment: Looking at the API code for com_content it seems to just pass the data back to the com_content model/article in the Admin directory so I would think it would be triggering the same plugin.

Comment: Please add this as the answer @Irata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API code for com_content it seems to just pass the data back to the com_content model/article in the Admin directory so I would think it would be triggering the same plugin.